# Collections.sort by a date property on the objects in a list

Tags: java, sorting

How do I use Collections.sort to sort list of objects with the following properties?

I'd like to sort the list by date.

```
public Comment {
    private Timestamp date;
    private String description;

}
```

Of course, there are getters and setters as well.

Thanks!

Comment: And what did you try to accomplish that?

Comment: I didn't see the other.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options you can create a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for creating your sort strategy, or define *natural-order* of your class implementing [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Example using Comparator:

```
public class Comment{

private Timestamp date;
private String description;
public static final Comparator<Comment> commentComparator = new MyComparator();

//getter and setter

static class MyComparator implements Comparator<Comment>{

            @Override
            public int compare(Comment o1, Comment o2) {
                // here you do your business logic, when you say where a comment is greater than other
            }    
}

}
```

And in client code.

Example:

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
//fill array with values
Collections.sort(list, Comment.commentComparator );
```

Read more : [Collections#sort(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

If  you want to define natural-ordering of your class just define

```
public class Comment implements Comparable<Comment>{

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Comment o) {
           // do business logic here
        }
}
```

And in client code:

```
   Collections.sort(myList); // where myList is List<Comment>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use comparator, for example:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CommentComparator implements Comparator<Comment> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Comment o1, Comment o2) {
        return o1.getDate().compareTo( o2.getDate() );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Comment> list = new ArrayList<Comment>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Timestamp t = new Timestamp( System.currentTimeMillis() );
            Comment c = new Comment();
            c.setDate(t);
            c.setDescription( String.valueOf(i) );
            list.add(c);
        }

        Collections.sort(list, new CommentComparator());
    }
}
```